# C# System.Timers.Timer how to name its thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, timer

This is my main method:

```
   public static void main(){
        var timer1=createDebounceTimer("TIMER1");
        var timer2=createDebounceTimer("TIMER2");
    }
```

This is my timer build code:

```
    private System.Timers.Timer createDebounceTimer(string threadName){
        var debounceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(debounce * 1000);
        debounceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        debounceTimer.AutoReset = false;
        //here I need to name the timer with threadName var
        return debounceTimer;
    }
```

and this is a simple elapse event:

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
       log.Info("My log system need the name of my thread");
    }
```

**Question 1:**

How to name the thread of the timer? I need this for logging purposes, in detail I would like to name the thread of the Elapsed event.

**Question 2:**

Can I be sure that there will be one **dedicated thread** per timer in case of multiple timer creation?

Comment: You could inherit from System.Timers.Timer and add your own properties (name) to it.

Comment: The Elapsed event handler is called on a threadpool thread.  You have no guarantee whatsoever that it will be the exact same thread the next time.  If this is important then you need to stop using the Timer class and cook something up yourself with the Thread class that loops while calling Sleep().  This is unwise, threads are very expensive objects.

Answer (score 2):

Was wondering on this as well.  Not sure how this stands up, but why not do something like this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "CustomThreadName-" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
   log.Info("My log system need the name of my thread");
}
```

Log4Net will faithfully display "CustomThreadName-..." in the logs when using '%thread' in conversionPattern.  The ManagedThreadId will at least give you uniqueness in your logs.

Comment: Addendum: when applying this, I got the error "System.InvalidOperationException: Thread.Name can only be set once." Reason: It was set each time the timer callback was called. So be aware when using this proposed solution